# Addressing the "I just lost a lot of money in Monero. Should I sell?" question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answers

As most of you already know, StackExchange's biggest draw is how it populates Google's search engine with Monero content, so when people type "Why is my Monero wallet doing X?" the answer quickly appears.

I think we should address questions about losing or making money in this investment. People are going to be searching for these anyways, so it's probably a good idea that we just have some stock answer so that people have something, anything really, to read and process their situation.

I understand the best answers are highly subjective and opinion based. Every "investor" in Monero is going to have a different risk tolerance and time horizon, so there isn't one good answer for everybody. But that shouldn't dissuade us from providing some sort of objective answer to their dilemma.

---

**Example question:** "I just lost a lot of money by investing in Monero. Should I sell?"

**Possible answer:** "The answer to this question is going to change from person to person. Really, nobody on the internet has the ability to know your personal situation and whether or not you should buy or sell Monero. Your best solution is to contact a financial advisor with your specific situation and see what they say.

What we can say is that "investing" in Monero is highly speculative. It's a normal day where the price rises or falls by 10%, and a normal week where it rises or falls by 25%. As a result, people should never put more into Monero than they can stand to lose completely. As a rule of thumb, if the price swings are causing you to lose sleep at night, you've probably invested too much."

---

What do you guys think? I feel its better to have this answer available than nothing at all.

Comment: I can't stop you from posting it, but I will probably just close it, see my answer [here](http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/q/102/100)

Comment: I agree with @5chdn. Those type of questions closed as off topic on the Ethereum and Bitcoin stacks and I see no reason why Monero should be different.

Comment: Alright I'll defer to the group consensus on this one. But for future discussions my vote has been cast. It is possible to give objective answers to these types of questions.

Comment: Another option would be to ask the mods at http://money.stackexchange.com/ if they would like us to merge this type of question to their stack. It seem much more closely related to asset allocation and risk tolerance than Monero to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a good idea with a brief comment, something along those lines and then explain that the Monero Stack Exchange is not a place for opinion based questions.  Then link them to the [XMRTrader Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/xmrtrader/), [Bitcointalk Monero speculation thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=753252.0) or the [Monero markets channel.](http://irc://chat.freenode.net/#monero-markets)

I don’t see heavy down voting questions like these as a good idea in a new Stack Exchange like this one, but filling up the Stack Exchange with price speculation is not a good idea either. I think people come here to learn about Monero and not read through people's opinions about the price.

Comment: If this is not a place for such questions, then why creating it in the first place?

Comment: I believe this Stack Exchange is for questions and answer about Monero, the technology behind it, how to use it, etc. Not for people's opinion about the price.